# Open dialog box on click on multiple buttons of similar name

Tags: jquery, html, cakephp-1.3

I have to **jquery** to show dialog box , but there is a problem, I have multiple buttons of similar name, example : btnEditUser-1, btnEditUser-2, btnEditUser-3

I have to call same function for every buttons to call AJAX function.

Please suggest how can I do it?

Please find the html/javascript code for reference:

**cakephp code to print html**

```
if($user['id']=="1" or ((strtotime(date("Y-m-d"))-strtotime($searchres[$i]['documents']['uploadtime']))<172800))
    {

    echo $this->Form->button('Edit User', array('type'=>'button','id'=>'edituser-'.$id,'name'=>'edituser-'.$id,'value'=>$id));
}
```

I have to write following function in jquery which recieve the value sent by button(mentioned above):

```
function showedituser(doc_id) {
        var data = {doc_id : doc_id};
        var divname = $('#dialog-edituser');
        $("#dialog-markup").dialog("open");
        var url = 'documents/getassigned_users';
        callajax(url, data, divname);
        return false;
   }
```

Comment: why not use a class then?

Comment: thanks roasted for comment. But I am new in jquery, please suggest me that how do I use class for such case.

Comment: Have you tried to understand/learn the code you are using or not? If yes, you shouldn't have difficulty to use a class. Now, let us know where you are stuck and someone maybe could help you. If you show no effort, no one will help you for sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a common class to all those buttons. For example:

```
<input type="button" id="btnEditUser-1" class="btnEditUser" >
<input type="button" id="btnEditUser-2" class="btnEditUser" >
.......................
<input type="button" id="btnEditUser-n" class="btnEditUser" >
```

An then add a click handler to all those (with jQuery for example):

```
$('.btnEditUser').on('click', function(event){
    //If you're in a form you may want to prevent the default behaviour (sumbit the form)
    event.preventDefault();
    //Now most-probably you'd like to do something different for each button clicked:
    var buttonIdParts = $( this ).attr('id').split('-');
    //Now you're left with the number from the id
    var buttonId = buttonIdParts[1];
    switch(buttonId)
    {
    case 1:
       // execute code block 1
       //AJAX Call, whatever
        break;
    case 2:
      //  execute code block 2
        break;
    default:
    //code to be executed if n is different from case 1 and 2
    }
});
```

Rather than parsing the `id` you can also use a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/):

```
<input type="button" id="btnEditUser-1" class="btnEditUser" data-button-id="1">
<input type="button" id="btnEditUser-2" class="btnEditUser" data-button-id="2">
...............
<input type="button" id="btnEditUser-n" class="btnEditUser" data-button-id="n">
```

and get the correct id directly:

```
//This goes inside the events handler
var buttonId = $( this ).attr('data-button-id');
```

It is also **important to notice** that within the event handler callback function the context of `this` is the button that was just clicked and `$( this )` is jQuery selecting this button (from the DOM) and creating a [jQuery Object](http://api.jquery.com/Types/%5C) out of it.